# How can I create a quote command for discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I've been trying to make a quote command for my discord bot but I cannot seem to get it quite right, I've looked up sources and I still can't seem to get it to work. I am new to discord.js but I understand it for the most part, sorry for any mess.`

```
    const replies = ["quote1","quote2","quote3","quote4"];

    const reply = Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length);

    const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;

    const dmessage = message.channel.send(replies[reply]).then(async (start) => {
        if (dmessage === replies[0]){
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter,
            {max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time']}).then(async (collected) => {
                if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == 'answer') {
                    message.reply('Correct!');
                } else message.reply('Wrong!');
            }).catch(() => {
                message.reply("No answer! Canceled.");
            });
        
    }})`
```

Comment: "I can't get it to work" is not enough to diagnose a problem. What's going wrong? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: `dmessage` in an entire message object. You're looking for `dmessage.content`